# xcode 4.3.2 process hangs

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I have run into a rather annoying bug in Xcode 4.3.2.

If you run a process from within Xcode, then stop the simulator directly (outside of Xcode), Xcode still shows the process as running and effectively disables any further interaction with the simulator.

I can't stop the process from within Xcode (no response), and I can't start a new process either as Xcode sees the simulator as being in use. Shutting down the simulator does not notify Xcode either, so I have no option but to shut down Xcode and open it up again But even that does't work as Xcode hangs whilst trying to shut down the process too! So I have to force quit Xcode!

Has anyone found a way round this? I realise I should now only operate the simulator from within Xcode, but I am used to being able to operate the simulator independently.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having similar issues with Xcode 4.3.2. I fixed them by doing the following:

1. Launch Xcode.
2. Close any open projects.
3. Open Organizer.
4. Delete project form left panel using the gear icon on the bottom left. Select "Remove from Organizer...". This clears all the data about your project that Xcode has cached (indexes, DerivedData, Snapshots, etc.).

5). Re-open project.

Since doing this, my Xcode hanging issues have disappeared.

Comment: Tried it, did not help for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I follow when this happens:

- Start the simulator if it isn’t already running
- Choose the option “Reset Content and Settings…” from the iOS Simulator menu
- Clean and rebuild the project